# nlog longdate always returns default

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I have the following NLog target tag (It's all on one line, I just split it up here for simple reading):

```
<target 
    name="FileLogger" 
    xsi:type="File" 
    fileName="e:\logs\${date:format=yyMMdd}_debug.log" 
    archiveNumbering="Sequence" 
    archiveAboveSize="1000000" 
    layout="${longdate} | ${level:uppercase=true} | ${event-context:item=workName} | ${logger} | ${callsite:filename=true}  | ${message}" 
    archiveEvery="Day"/>
```

When I look in my folder, my logs are named:

```
010101_debug.log
010101_debug.0.log
010101_debug.1.log
etc.
```

So why is the date always 010101? The `${longdate}` in layout doesn't work either.
If you need any more of my code, please let me know.

Comment: Your problem sounds like it could be similar to a question that I answered some time ago. Are you creating LogEventInfo objects and logging them with the Log method?  If so, read this and see if it helps.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344430/why-cant-nlog-read-the-current-date/13690779#13690779

Comment: I tried to reproduce this one but couldn't. I tried version 2.1.0, 3.0.0 and 3.1.0. What version of NLog are you using?

Comment: @ChristiaanvanBergen I'm using version 3.1.0. But I solved it ^^ I'll add an answer explaining how I got it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it!

I made my own functions in a helper-class that looked like this:

```
public static void Error(string workName, string message, string logcontext, string exMessage = "")
{
    LogEventInfo logEvent = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Error, logcontext, message + (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(exMessage) ? ": " : string.Empty) + exMessage);
    logEvent.Properties["workName"] = workName;
    logger.Log(typeof(InternalLogger), logEvent);
}
```

And the same for all log-levels. I dont know why, but that solved it ^^

Comment: Great that your initial problem is solved, but I still don't get why it went wrong in the first place nor why this piece of code solved it.

Comment: @ChristiaanvanBergen me neither ^^'

Comment: See the link in my comment on the original question.  If the OP was using the default constructor for LogEventInfo as part of his logging workflow, then he will see get a default value for the date/time and that default value will NOT be the current date/time.